# WooCommerce 'all' orders no longer being displayed - how may I debug/fix

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I've just noticed that we seem to have a bug with our store.  The 'all' orders selection is showing as empty but the other sub catergories such as completed, on hold and pending etc are there.

I'm not sure what could've caused this, I presume a plugin or an update but I'm also not sure how to debug or get into the logs to check.

Any advice would be brilliant, thank you.

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue with WP Update 5.02.

View the topic [HERE](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22271).

And the fix [HERE](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/22273).

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with a change in WordPress 5.0.2. The issue has been fixed in WooCommerce 3.5.3, which was just released: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/12/20/woocommerce-3-5-3-release-notes/

Answer (score 0):

If the issues persist after this type of test, then try updating the database by adding this link below after your site domain name.

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&do_update_woocommerce=true
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is a conflict between your theme and another plugin. In other words, there are two parts of code that give conflicting signals. Try the following steps:

1. Switch to a default WordPress theme.
2. Temporarily deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce and the
   WooCommerce extensions
3. Reactivate the plugins one by one and detect the defective ones.

You can find more information about the steps [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/how-to-test-for-conflicts/).

Comment: I have the same issue. I can confirm that deactivating all plugins ( bar Woocommerce ) does not fix it. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323531/woocommerce-all-orders-tab-says-no-orders-found

Answer (score -1):

You can enable debugging in your wp-config.php file.

Add this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

It enables debugging and will log any problems in a file "debug.log"